# Como criar um objeto em 3D

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Olá,
Estou pensando em fazer um site que esteja fixado em uma tela única. Quando clicado no menu de opções, as telas ficariam apresentadas como um slide, semelhante ao que acontece hoje nos sistemas Android, no menu de aplicativos. Sendo que cada película daquelas estaria uma "página" do meu site. Se alguém tiver ideia de onde posso começar eu agradeço.

Comment: Sua pergunta, além de ser bastante ampla, é principalmente baseada em opiniões. Para evitar de ganhar votos negativos, é interessante ler a área *Perguntando* da [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber quais são os tipos de perguntas aceitas aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom você pode começar criando o body com a altura exata da tela do usuário.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var altura = $(window).height();
body.style.height = altura+'px';
});
```

Crie as div's de conteúdo com height 100%;

Com um menu (pelicula?) você irá fazer a chamada pra cada conteúdo.

As div's terão display: none, e por jquery você vai ocultando a div q não precisa ser mais exibida e mostrando a que precisa exibir

exemplo:

```
    $('#Ltest').click(function(){

    if(ltest2.style.display == 'block')
    {
        $('#ltest2').fadeOut();
        $('#ltest').delay(400).fadeToggle('slow');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#ltest').fadeToggle('slow');
    }
```

Claro que esse é só um exemplo ou uma forma de ser feito.. Existem outras 600mil possibilidades, tudo depende de sua criatividade e paciência de aprendizado. Você pediu um começo, ai está.

Comment: Muito bom. Vou fazer e ver no que dá. Obrigado